# Which should I use, ListView.builder or Column?

Tags: flutter, dart

We can use `ListView.builder` for lists. However, I found another way using `Column`.

Here are two sample codes:

##### `ListView.builder`

```dart
List list = ["A", "B", "C"];

…

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(list[index]),
),
```

---

##### `Column`

```dart
List list = ["A", "B", "C"];

…

Column(children: list.map((element) => Text(element)).toList())
```

So, my question is, which code should I use?

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListView.builder` is useful when you have a large number of items that can change dynamically, as it only builds the `children` that are currently visible. It also allows you to easily scroll through the list of items.

`Column`, on the other hand, is a layout widget that arranges its `children` vertically. It's useful when you have a small number of `children` that you want to stack vertically and the height of the `children` is known.

Here are a few guidelines to help you decide:

- If you have a large number of items that can change dynamically and
  you want to allow the user to scroll through them, use
  `ListView.builder`.
- If you have a small number of items that you want
  to stack vertically and the height of the `children` is known, use
  `Column`.
- If you want to build a list of items with a fixed number of
  `children` and you want to stack them vertically, you can use `Column`
  with `ListView` as child. It's also possible to use both
  `ListView.builder` and `Column` together, depending on the requirement.

It's always best to experiment with both and decide which one works best for your specific layout and use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use base on you need.

Short answer:

> Use `ListView.builder` when you have a long list. the `ListView.builder`
> constructor creates items as they are scrolled onto the screen.
> And for `ListView` it needs cross axis shrink wrap behavior. Means, child width is equal to screen size width.

You can read this documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists

---

Of course they are different. `Column` doesn't support scroll function. Then you need to wrap with `SingleChildScrollView` but also there are some pros and cons.

Also I recommend my article here where I explain more about it: https://medium.com/easyread/my-october-flutter-notes-2-6e0c78cf2e56